# How to programatically ad securitySchema to swagger.yaml

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger

I have a swagger.yaml file containing definition of my API. I'm using the following piece of code to add it as a swagger resource and display it in swagger-ui:

```java
@Primary
@Bean
public SwaggerResourcesProvider swaggerResourcesProvider(InMemorySwaggerResourcesProvider defaultResourcesProvider) {
    return () -> {
        SwaggerResource wsResource = new SwaggerResource();
        wsResource.setName("Documentation");
        wsResource.setSwaggerVersion("3.0");
        wsResource.setLocation("/swagger.yaml");

        List<SwaggerResource> resources = new ArrayList<>(defaultResourcesProvider.get());
        resources.add(wsResource);
        return resources;
    };
}
```

However, I need to have a different security schema authorization URL for each instance of my application (dev, test, prod). The question is how to achieve it? Is it possible to programmatically add the security schema, which will be parametrized based on f.e. env variables?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using the following:

```java
@Bean
public OpenAPI openAPI() {
    return new OpenAPI()
            .components(new Components().addSecuritySchemes("jwtScheme",
                new SecurityScheme().type(SecurityScheme.Type.APIKEY).in(SecurityScheme.In.HEADER).name("Authorization")));
}
```

You can get whatever environment variables you want to parameterize this configuration. You can read more about this at https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api#10-swagger-ui-with-an-oauth-secured-api.